# PHP check if a value says true, if yes do this - doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a simple vote system that generates a shuffled code after you have voted.
I have a little callback system that checks if the user voted on the site.

Looks like this:

http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=82.81.33.168

187 = server ID on top list
IP = The ip that has just voted.

If it says true when you go to this page, that means that IP has voted for that server ID.
If it says false, that means the IP hasn't voted for the server ID.

I have just voted, as you see it says true.

Now to check if voted I do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $check_GTL = file_get_contents("http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if ($check_GTL != "true") {
                $errors[] = "Sorry, but it seems like you haven't voted on all links, please contact Jony.";
        }
```

That line checks if you have voted:

```
$check_GTL = file_get_contents("http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

But for some random reason, the script tells me that check_GTL is not 'true'.
Yet it is true....

What is wrong with it?

Thanks!

All of it:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $check_GTL = file_get_contents("http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if ($check_GTL != "true") {
                $errors[] = "Sorry, but it seems like you haven't voted on all links, please contact Jony.";
        }


if($check_GTL == "true") { // if($votes > 0 && $check_GTL == "true") { disab led $votes cause runelocus didnt work lately for some reason.

        $insert = "INSERT INTO votes(auth, ip, received, time) VALUES('".$auth."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '0', '".time()."')";
        $insert = $connect->query($insert) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        echo '<center><div class="movingerror" style="color: yellow">Thank you for voting! Your auth is <b>'.$auth.'</b>. Please type ::auth '.$auth.' to claim your reward</div></center>';


        $file = fopen("votes.txt", 'w');    
        fwrite($file, --$votes);
        fclose($file);
    }

}
```

Comment: what contains `$check_GTL` when you `var_dump()` it?

Comment: `file_get_contents()`: `The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure.`. Since it clearly fails, echo the url you query and try it in browser and check error logs on why does it fails.

Comment: It's also worth checking that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: It works on my other host, why? what have I done wrong with php installation?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Misunderstood the question, strike this.

file_get_contents() returns a boolean value not a string. There's a huge difference between:

```
if ($check_GTL == "true")
```

and:

```
if ($check_GTL == true)
```

You want the latter.

Comment: Even just true doesn't work.
The script have worked before, I have no idea why it stopped working..

Comment: @Jonykale Most likely because the response you're getting has changed?

Comment: Run `var_dump($check_GTL)` and see what you're actually getting.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns a string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I have no idea, the website responding a string named 'true' and 'false' if you haven't voted.

Comment: OH wait, is the page itself sending the string "true"? My mistake, I thought you were checking to see if the page existed.

Comment: it says: bool(false) with var_dump.

Comment: In that case, file_get_contents() itself is failing.

Comment: Maybe the page doesn't allow you to fetch contents?

Comment: [Sun Feb 24 23:18:57 2013] [error] [client 82.81.33.168] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: check_GTL in /var/www/html/vote/index.php on line 65

Comment: Line 65: if($check_GTL == "true") {

Comment: How could the page not allow me to fetch contents if I can access it and see the string 'true' ?