# My File get contents function doesn't work on this host

Tags: php

PHP 5.2.0

My php.ini: http://pastebin.com/AXsDAzRR

Problem:

The function File get contents doesn't work on my web server.

Read more about this problem here: [PHP check if a value says true, if yes do this - doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055984/php-check-if-a-value-says-true-if-yes-do-this-doesnt-work)

I did die($check_GTL) on this host before it checked if its true of false;

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $check_GTL = file_get_contents("http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=82.81.33.168");
                die($check_GTL);    
        if ($check_GTL != "true") {
                //$errors[] = "Sorry, but it seems like you haven't voted on all links, please contact Jony.";
                } else {
                echo 'voted';
                }
        }
```

On my current host, after clicking the submit button, it sends me to a blank page.

On my other host, after clicking the submit button, it sends me to a page that says 'true'.

This is a very weird error, and 100% related to my first host.

Any more info needed?
Thanks for the support!

Comment: Have you enabled error_reporting? And allow_url_fopen?

Comment: I think because allow_url_fopen is disabled see [This](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On

Comment: why do you don't true this function witch Javascript (jQuery:post)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://gamingtoplist.net/?hasvoted=187&ip=82.81.33.168");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$check_GTL = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($check_GTL != "true") {
                //$errors[] = "Sorry, but it seems like you haven't voted on all links, please contact Jony.";
                } else {
                echo 'voted';
                }
```

on my localserver (ub untu xampp) it works

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on the host where it's not working. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php